# get values from 'time' command via bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, time

I want to run some executables with the time command

```
time myexec -args
```

How can I store only the time output to a variable in bash? Thats the only part I care about for this script, not the output of the executable. Is there a way to get that value, or will I have to parse the text of the entire command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I found this as well - [How to store a substring of the output of "time" function in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457953/how-to-store-a-substring-of-the-output-of-time-function-in-bash-script)

Probably closer to what I was looking for

Comment: This should be a close-as-duplicate vote, not an answer.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. It needs some detail in order to avoid link rot.

Answer (score 26):

See [BashFAQ/032](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

All output (stdout, stderr and `time`) captured in a variable:

```
var=$( { time myexec -args; } 2>&1 )
```

Output to stdout and stderr go to their normal places:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
var=$( { time myexec -args 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )  # Captures time only.
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

Comment: The `;` is mighty important to the command.  It is what I was missing on my command.  I kept getting syntax errors.  Thank you!

Comment: `$ var=$( { time ls -args 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1 )` / 
`$ echo $var` / 
`-bash: 3: Bad file descriptor real 0m0.002s user 0m0.001s sys 0m0.001s`

Comment: @Sixtyfive: (Note that `-args` was a dummy placeholder in my example which you carried into the command you posted. Not related to your error, however.) I don't know why you got that error unless the file descriptor was closed in another command.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
TIME="$(sh -c "time myexec -args &> /dev/null" 2>&1)"
```

Comment: `&>` isn't valid in a POSIX sh script, and a shell invoked under the name `sh` guarantees you no functionality not specified in the standard. (For example, this will absolutely break on Debian or Ubuntu systems where `sh` is implemented by dash).

Comment: Good point, but the question is specifically for bash.

Comment: The OP may be *invoking* this code from bash, but when you run `sh -c`, that's no longer bash (if you're on Debian, Ubuntu, etc); which shell is used to *invoke* `sh` is irrelevant to the question of which shell actually *implements* `sh` on a given system.

Answer (score 0):

BASH has its built-in variant of `time`. If you do a `man time` you will find that a lot of those option listed there won't work with `time` command. The man page warns BASH users that they may use explicit path to `time`.

The explicit path is `/usr/bin/time` on Ubuntu, but you can find it out with `$ which time`.

With the proper path, you can use the `-f` or `--format` option and a lot of formatting parameters that will nicely format your result which you can store to a variable as well.

> STUFF_HERE=`/usr/bin/time -f %E sleep 1
>   2>&1`

Comment: That's a backtick there, not an apostrophe.

Comment: You wouldn't have to explain that if you [used `$()` instead of backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).