# How to use time command but only to time part of the script

Tags: shell, unix, time, solaris, ksh

just for the record i am running on ksh in a Unix Solaris system.
I have a script that could look like this:

```
awk '{ do stuff here }'

for n in x {
    echo $something | awk '{ do more stuff here }'
}
```

I know that i can use `time` in the console when i am running the script, for example, if the name of the file would be file_name, i would run it like this: `time ksh file_name`, but like this i get returned the run time of the whole script, I need only the run time of the `for` in order to do some calculations in comparison with another script. Is it even possible that i can invoke the `time` inside the script, so lets say i would add it before `for` so that it would calculate only that part? Also i would like to know if it is possible to have two `time` for one script, so you would get the run time of two different parts of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all variables in a Bash script are global, you can store that `for` in a function and call it prepending `time`:

```
my_for_function () {
    for n in x {
        echo $something | awk '{ do more stuff here }'
    }
}

awk '{ do stuff here }'

time my_for_function   # here you call `time`
```

Then you run the script normally.

#### Little example

```
$ cat silly_script.sh

myfunc() {
    for x in "${a[@]}"
        do
             echo "$x --"
             sleep 1
        done

}

awk 'BEGIN {print "i am here"}'
a=(1 2 3 4)

time myfunc

echo "i am done"
```

Let's run it:

```
$ bash silly_script.sh
i am here
1 --
2 --
3 --
4 --

real    0m4.008s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
i am done
```

Comment: you said about bash script in the start, but i am running on ksh, will this work in ksh?

Comment: @hedgehog oh, true. I don't have `ksh` installed here. Mind to test this script in your installation?

Comment: just did, it doesnt give an error, it prints the echo "I am here" but then does nothign and not exiting the script. `Yes,Master? ksh te_script
i am here`       i suppose its getting stucked in the loop..

Comment: @hedgehog I just installed `ksh93` and ran the script. It is running fine. Since there is a `sleep 1` in it, every item in the loop takes one second to show.

Comment: i waited like 20 seconds and nothing happened, anyways i intergrated your sollution to my script and YES! its working :) you are beautifull as always, though one more fast question, if i use the time as you said for the function it prints out this `real     0m0.03s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s`
, and if i run time for the whole script it shows this `real     0m0.171s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.018s`
,  how can i make the time that i use for the function to show all digits on milisecond? as the other does.

Comment: @hedgehog I am not sure if I understand you. I see both outputs in the format `XmY.YYs`. That is, minutes, seconds and portions of seconds. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: the time that i use with the function it shows this `real 0m0.03s `and the time that i use when i call the script it gives this `real 0m0.171s` , dont you see the difference, the first has one less digit, so it doesnt show the whole milisecond as the other one.... and i need it to show all three digits as the second `time` does.

Comment: @hedgehog OK, I see. Well, for this you have to do some mangling with the data. I suggest you start checking [get values from 'time' command via bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4617688/1983854). Then, you can use `printf` to define the number of float digits you want to show.

Comment: sooo same question this is written for bash, is it going to work for ksh?

Comment: @hedgehog are you really asking this? You should try it yourself, I cannot spoonfeed you :D

Comment: i just asked cause i cant run it still on my script i am working on somethign else right now...