# how to set timer for each script that runs

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk, printf

Dear friend and colleges

it's lovely to be here in stack overflow the best cool site

Under /tmp/scripts we have around 128 scripts that perform many tests

As

```
verify_dns.sh
verify_ip.sh
verify_HW.sh
```

And so on

we decided to run all scripts under the current folder - /tmp/scfipt
with the following code

```
script_name=` find /tmp/scripts  -maxdepth 1  -type f -name "verify_*"   -exec basename {} \; `

for i in $script_name
do
  echo running the script - $i
  /tmp/scripts/$i
done
```

So output is like this

```
running the script - verify_dns.sh
running the script - verify_ip.sh
.
.
```

What we want to add  - is the ability to print also the time that script runs

As the following example

```
running the script - verify_dns.sh   - 16.3 Sec
running the script - verify_ip.sh    - 2.5 Sec
.
.
```

My question , how we can add this ability in my code ?

Note - os version - is redhat 7.2

Comment: `time` command will compute the timings but you need to work on formatting the output.  GNU version has some formatting options to help you.

Comment: ok , thank you for the help

Comment: If you don't need the fractions, sometimes it's handy to have actual timestamps. `trap date debug` with do that with one call at the top of the script, but it leaves you to figure out the differences. Applying the same logic to Simonare's first solution would be similar: `trap 'echo $SECONDS; SECONDS=0' debug` which might also be easy, if fractions aren't important.

Comment: I use `ttic` and `ttoc` utilities written by an superuser user and shared [here](https://superuser.com/questions/228801/measure-script-execution-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for calculating seconds you can use

```
SECONDS=0 ; 
your_bash_script ; 
echo $SECONDS
```

for more sensitive calculation

```
start=$(date +'%s%N') 
your_shell_script.sh
echo "It took $((($(date +'%s%N') - $start)/100000)) miliseconds"
```

for internal time function

```
time your_shell_script.sh
```

**Edit: example provided for OP**

```
for i in $script_name
do
  echo running the script - $i
  start=$(date +'%s%N')
  /tmp/scripts/$i
  echo "It took $((($(date +'%s%N') - $start)/100000)) miliseconds"
done
```

---

```
for i in $script_name
do
  echo running the script - $i
  time /tmp/scripts/$i
done
```

Comment: but not clearly how I need to add this syntax in my code , so finally I will get the time as I explained

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: Ha ok , let me test it on my machine , one memento please

Comment: one little problem , I see many script running lest then 1 sec , so the output is It took 0 seconds , but not so logical to get 0 value

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `time` command to tell you how long each one took:

```
TIMEFORMAT="%E"
for i in $script_name
do
  echo -en "running the script - $i\t - "
  exec 3>&1 4>&2
  var=$( { time /tmp/scripts/$i 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1)  # Captures time only
  exec 3>&- 4>&-

  echo "$var Sec"
done
```

This works regardless of if your scripts produce any output/stderr.  See this link for capturing only the output of time:  [get values from 'time' command via bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617489/get-values-from-time-command-via-bash-script)

Comment: the output is like this - running the script - verify_dns.sh -\t1.39

Comment: why "\t" is printed?

Comment: I forgot to add the `-e` flag to echo to tell it to print a tab character.

Comment: another thing is the the "Sec" word is on the second line instead to be in the first line

Comment: "Sec" being on the second line means there's probably a newline character from the output of time. You can remove it by using something like `tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: even I used the tr -d , the Sec jump to the second line

Comment: example - Sec Secrunning the script

Comment: I forgot that you have to use the bash builtin `time` for this kind of redirection. By default it didn't have the format you wanted, so I used /usr/bin/time, which was incorrect. Instead, you need to set the TIMEFORMAT variable.

Comment: not so good because time is in internal shell and not recognized , time must be have full path

Comment: Why would the internal shell not recognize the time command? Oh, or did you mean the TIMEFORMAT? If that's what you mean, you can try exporting it, or just put the time format directly in front of the command.

Although, for me, it works even with using an internal shell. I'm not sure what's happening on your end then.

Comment: I test it , when you put only time without full path then script failed on that , and when I set export TIME=/usr/bin/time , and I set the TIME inside , then again we get the same problem that "sec" inserted on the next line

Comment: second little esthetic problem , is that time printed values are not alignment , and that because some script names are short and some are long so in that case we get non  alignment printing

Comment: Are you using bash? Does red hat version of bash not having time? But yes, to do the capturing of only time above, you need the bash builtin, otherwise it doesn't work. This solution was involving the builtin time command. How did @Simonare's answer work for you?

Comment: For formatting, I would say you could use the builtin printf, but I don't know if you have those builtins or not. Either way, I have to go now. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't put the output on the same line, this might suit your needs.

```
for i in $script_name
do { set -x;
     time "$i";
   } 2>&1 | grep -Ev '^(user|sys|$)'
done
```