# How to extract time value for the find command using bash script?

Tags: bash

I understand that I need to redirect output and error so that the command output is stored. However, I am unable to get the correct information inside the variable. How can I do so?

I tried following the post - [How to store a substring of the output of "time" function in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457953/how-to-store-a-substring-of-the-output-of-time-function-in-bash-script)

```
TIMEFORMAT='%3lR'
test=$( time ls -l /  > /dev/null)
echo $test
```

Here is my output

```
$ sudo ./test.sh
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2980maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+144minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617489/get-values-from-time-command-via-bash-script

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457953